# Cloud Run returns 400 Bad Request with Custom Domain

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-run

I have previously deployed a lot of services to Cloud Run but this is my first time deploying a NodeJs server. It got successfully deployed and is also working perfectly. The problem arises when I map a custom domain to it. It works with the generated URL but not with the mapped URL. Whenever I hit the mapped URL, it returns **400 Bad Request**

My NodeJS code:

```js
const app = require('express')();
const cors = require('cors');
const server = require('http').createServer(app);

// routes
const home = require('./src/routes');

app.use(cors());
app.use('/', home);

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;

server.listen(PORT, '0.0.0.0', () => console.log(`Server listening on port ${PORT}`));
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM node:16

# Create app directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# Install app dependencies
# A wildcard is used to ensure both package.json AND package-lock.json are copied
# where available (npm@5+)
COPY package*.json ./

# If you are building your code for production
RUN npm ci --only=production

# Bundle app source
COPY . .

EXPOSE 5000

CMD [ "node", "server.js" ]
```

Curl

```sh
curl -v https://<subdomain.domain.com>
```

```
*   Trying 17x.xxx.xxx.xxx:443...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to <subdomain.domain.com> (17x.xxx.xxx.xxx) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Encrypted Extensions (8):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, CERT verify (15):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS change cipher, Change cipher spec (1):
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSL connection using TLSv1.3 / TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
* ALPN, server accepted to use h2
* Server certificate:
*  subject: CN=<subdomain.domain.com>
*  start date: May 29 15:31:03 2021 GMT
*  expire date: Aug 27 16:31:03 2021 GMT
*  subjectAltName: host "<subdomain.domain.com>" matched cert's "<subdomain.domain.com>"
*  issuer: C=US; O=Google Trust Services LLC; CN=GTS CA 1D4
*  SSL certificate verify ok.
* Using HTTP2, server supports multi-use
* Connection state changed (HTTP/2 confirmed)
* Copying HTTP/2 data in stream buffer to connection buffer after upgrade: len=0
* Using Stream ID: 1 (easy handle 0x565480c42e10)
> GET / HTTP/2
> Host: <subdomain.domain.com>
> user-agent: curl/7.68.0
> accept: */*
> 
* Connection state changed (MAX_CONCURRENT_STREAMS == 100)!
< HTTP/2 400 
< content-type: text/html
< x-content-type-options: nosniff
< referrer-policy: same-origin
< x-cloud-trace-context: d0038e2821f61d26f77c95ead4f75d96
< date: Mon, 31 May 2021 19:54:12 GMT
< server: Google Frontend
< content-length: 143
< 

<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bad Request (400)</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Bad Request (400)</h1><p></p>
</body>
</html>
* Connection #0 to host <subdomain.domain.com> left intact
```

Comment: Assuming that you have waited long enough for the custom domain to be deployed and is mapped correctly, use curl or postman to test your endpoint. Post the request and response in your question including request and response headers.

Comment: @JohnHanley Yeah it's been more than 48 hrs since I added the custom domain. I have updated the curl response.

Comment: I need to see the request and response with the headers. The plain HTML does nothing to help debug this. Use `curl -v`.

Comment: @JohnHanley I have updated the response. For some internal reasons, I cannot reveal the IP and the domain. I have replaced those with the respective placeholder.

Comment: You can redact domain names and IPs, but I need to see the full request and response.  This includes the curl command you are issuing. The trace that you just added does not show the 400 error. Instead, it shows a 302 response. Invest time in learning tools like `curl` as they can simplify debugging problems like yours.

Comment: @JohnHanley Sorry for the inconvenience. I have updated my question.

Comment: @DebdutGoswami 4XX errors means that is something wrong with your container, the server, your code. Cloud Run balancer acts fine as CURL details show, but the backend, your container doesn't act good, and it returns 4XX errors. Make sure you check your logs, you make additional logs. Try testing the custom domain with a simple service, and go further from there.

Comment: @Pentium10 There is just a hello world code as you can see. I even tried deploying a new service and it is exactly behaving like this. This is literally my first time using nodejs so I guess I am missing something.

Comment: then check cors specific setup, hardcode your URL into the options (as inferring the custom domain could be your issue) see cors with options here: https://stackabuse.com/handling-cors-with-node-js

Comment: The curl trace is not pointing to the problem. To confirm, the same deployment works using the Google URL, but generates a 400 error using a custom domain? Which region? Add your deployment command to your question. Check Cloud Logging for error messages. Add those to your question.